# Rails Render a partial inside partial with collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rendering

I have a partial nested inside collection of partial. For example

```
<= render partial: "users/user", collection: @users, as: :user %>
```

inside `_user.html.erb` partial, I am rendering another partial as follow:

```
<%= render partial: "users/user_info", locals: {user: user}  %>
```

It works this way, but the problem is that it is rendering `_user_info.html.erb` partial for each user object and this makes it to take a long time. How can I avoid this? Any suggestions?

Comment: i think that you are saying that the partial user_info is rendered for each user inside of the user partial.  Is that right?

Comment: @Austio yes, thats correct.

Comment: your local :user is going to be shared throughout the render of partial.  You would do best to manually loop through to get the sub_partial to have the proper user context.

Comment: Hi @Austio, can you give such example of sub_partial? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering partials usually takes time. I think about 2 ways to reduce render time:

1. Reduce partial files, which means don't use partial.
2. Implement a proper caching strategy, in this case it's usually fragment caching.

> For more information about caching strategy in Rails, take a look at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching

Answer (score 1):

Rails will properly cache only top-level partial templates.
My suggestion is to use [content_for][1] feature to move user_info partial to the top too.
In your main layout:

```
<%= render partial: "users/user_info", collection: @users, as: :user %>
<%= render partial: "users/user", collection: @users, as: :user %>
```

In your 'user_info' partial:

```
<% content_for "user_info_#{user.id}" do %>
<!-- your user_info content -->
<% end %>
```

In your 'user' partial:

```
<!-- your user content -->
<%= content_for "user_info_#{user.id}"%>
```

In this case, both user_info and user partial templates will be cached properly, and rendering will take less time.
[1]: https://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for

Answer (score 0):

You should be using fragment caching along with multi fetch fragments which will give you a significant boost:
https://github.com/n8/multi_fetch_fragments 
(This gem is already a part of Rails 5)